# How to use Method Reference to get BigDecimal Value

Tags: java

I have  a Employee class as shown below

```
public class Employee {
    
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal salary;
    
    // setters and getters 
    
}
```

I am trying to use MethodReference to get the salary as shown below

```
public class TestExample {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            
            String salary  = Optional.ofNullable(emp)
                    .map(BigDecimal :: getSalary)
                    .map(String :: toString)
                    .orElse("");
        }
```

Any idea how to get salary using MethodReference only

**Seeing a issue at toString now**

```
String salry  = Optional.ofNullable(emp)
                .map(Employee  :: getSalary)
                .map(Employee :: toString)
                .orElse("");
```

Comment: what is the problem with your code?

Comment: `.map(Employee :: getSalary)`

Comment: You need to use `Employee ::getSalary`.

Comment: I don't see the point why you should be using a method reference here to get the salary. It makes sense when you're consuming a Stream of Employee but a single one you just can get the field. The Optional type also makes no sense right here..

Comment: @Jens , seeing  a issue when using toString

Comment: To use method reference you need to name the class which contains the method (not the type of the method's result!) and the method name. The `getSalary` is a method of Employee class, not BigDecimal, so to reference this method you need to use `Employee::getSalary`. Similarly, you want to use a String method of BigDecimal class later, so you need `BigDecimal::toString`, not `String::toString`

Comment: @Alex I think you should consider posting your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how the types are mutating. At the point where you map this thing to the salary you are working with a optional of type `BigDecimal` so it won't work.

```java
Optional<String> salary  = Optional.ofNullable(emp)
                .map(Employee::getSalary)
                .map(BigDecimal::toString);
```

Also in your case i don't really see the reason why you should be using a method reference to access the salary field, also i don't see a reason why you're using the optional type...